# $1.87= x/(0.80-x)$ Easy question with one difficult step

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am doing some very basic algebra work, and one of the examples has the question and how to solve for $x$. The answer looks like
$$1.87=\frac{x}{0.80-x}$$
multiply both sides by $0.80-x$
simplified
$$1.87(0.80-x)=x$$
which expanded looks like
$$1.496-1.87x=x$$
subtract $1.496$ from both sides

$$-1.87x=x-1.496$$
subtract $x$ from both sides
$$-1.87x-x=x-1.496-x$$
simplified
$$-2.87x=-1.496$$
solved
$$\frac{-2.87x}{-2.87} =\frac{-1.496}{-2.87}$$
$$x=0.52125$$

I can follow all of this and understand the steps, but where I am getting lost is when $-1.87x$ becomes $-2.87x$. Why does this happen? Would subtracting an $x$ just create $-1.87$?

Comment: Why didn’t you add $1.87x$ instead of subtracting $1.496$?  That would get you immediately $1.496=2.87x$.

Answer (score 2):

$$-1.87-1=-2.87$$

If it helps

$$-1.87-1=-(1.87+1)=-2.87$$

Comment: I understand that -(1.87+1)= -2.87, but the issue is that I cannot locate where the 1 was pulled from in the equation.

Comment: $-1.87x -x =-1.87x-1x$ , just like $1x=x$, we don't write them explicitly most of the time.

Comment: I think I understand now, thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the expression $-1.87x-x $, if there is no coefficient of the second term $x$, the coefficient of that term is understood to be $1$. Thus, $-1.87x - x$ can be rewritten as $$-1.87x - 1x$$$$ = (-1.87-1)x$$$$= -2.87x$$